# How do I get the page to reload to the same page Freeform Form submission?

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms

I have a [newsletter form](http://skimmer.disl.org) that pops up in a modal window and I would like the page to reload rather than go to a "thank you" page after you click submit. (see the sign up for our newsletter button in the footer).

According to Solspace [documentation](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#return):

**If [the return is] not specified, the user will be returned to the same page.**

But if I leave the return="" off the form, it reloads the parent site.

I have tried the following to override this but without success.

```
return="{if segment_1 == ''} http://skimmer.disl.org
        {if:elseif segment_2 != ''} segment_1/segment_2
        {if:else} segment_1
        {/if}
```

Is there some secret Solspace formula that I am not aware of? I would appreciate some guidance on resolving this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try not passing return parameter? Just remove the return parameter

Comment: Hi Mufi. Yes, that was the obvious solution as noted in my question above. However, the system ignored that and I was forced to use jQuery to resolve the problem.